# Colorbox modal opening/closing another Colorbox modal

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Greetings. I have a need to have a 'child' modal opended from a colorbox modal.
Form -> anchor -> opens modal ('parent') -> model has another anchor -> open modal 'child'

The problem is that when the 'child' modal closes via the

```
$.fn.colorbox.close()
```

Method this seems to close all the colorbox modal windows. I just need to close the 'child' (the second opened from the first modal), after I set a hidden on the 'parent' modal.

Any suggestions on how to close just the second colorbox window?

Using jQuery 1.3.2 and Colorbox 1.3.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I wound up doing was making the calling colorbox larger and then having the 'child' colorbox launch inside the parent colorbox; hiding the parents "Close" buttons. Then when the 'child' box is closed re-show the parents buttons.

Yes its ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might want the first colorbox instance to load an `iframe`. In this iframe you can load another colorbox.